# Google Maps Compose Clustering: make the selected marker different

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-markers

I see a huge performance difference in clustering about 1k of items. Even if I use a 990B .webp Image as an item, it has about 3x time against default markers (`clusterItemContent = null`) to re-cluster. And that time the UI is frozen even if I use this `Clustering` in `LaunchedEffect`.

How can I make the selected marker different (change size and/or color) to not to decrease performance?

```
Clustering(
    items = items,
    onClusterItemClick = {
        Timber.v("Marker clicked: ${it.name}")
        viewModel.selectItem(it)
        true
    },
    clusterItemContent = {
        var color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
        var size = Dimens.markerSize
        if (selectedItem == it) {
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary
            size = Dimens.markerSelectedSize
        }
        Image(painterResource(R.drawable.marker), Modifier.size(size), color)
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for now the simplest way is to add a new marker with same position to the content:

```
val content: (@Composable () -> Unit) = {
    Clustering(
        items = currentItems,
        onClusterItemClick = {
            Timber.v("Marker clicked: ${it.name}")
            viewModel.selectItem(it)
            true
        }
    )

    selectedItem?.let {
        Marker(state = MarkerState(it.position), zIndex = 1f, icon =  BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
    }
}
```

Possible to add `onClick` to this new marker to control if it's clicked again. Better way could be to remove the underlying (selected) marker and add it again after selection is changed (but reclustering will happen).